# StringEscapeUtils escapeHtml

Tags: html, escaping, stringescapeutils

Is there a difference between org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml and org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4 ?

Answer (score 5):

they come from different packages in fact

escapeHtml comes from org.commons.lang (lang 2.5 API) and let's you use a writer object. It can also escape string from an SQL source

escapeHtml4 is from org.commons.lang3 (lang 3.1 API) is specialy use to escape character from a HTML4 source. Nothing more, nothing less

They do the same job but i would recommend using "escapeHtml4" since its from a newer package

See : [EscapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) and [escapehtml](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aZp5dbujrxqEJ%3acommons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html+&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=ca)

Comment: I can see that they come from different packages.. my concern is if escapeHtml4 is backwards compatible...

Answer (score 1):

Note that `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()` has issues with apostrophes

Comment: In other words: do not use it for putting text into HTML documents.